# How to use javascript fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        $('#menu-fixed').toggle($(this).scrollTop() > 100 );
    });
</script>
```

I want to add a "fadeIn" effect but it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were really close, you just had to put the boolean passed to toggle in a conditional then execute the fade if true.

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 100){
       $('#menu-fixed').fadeIn(500);
    }
});
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/DfxtL/1/

Comment: Would be better with `position: fixed;` on the `#menu-fixed`

Comment: the problem is that when you get to the top of the page menu should disappear again.... :(

Answer (score -1):

I write this but I dont know if is correct....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 100){
       $('#menu-fixed').fadeIn(500);
    }
    else{
        if($(this).scrollTop() < 100) {
         $('#menu-fixed').fadeOut(500);
        }
    }   
});
</script>
```